# How to remove a binding follow an event in Svelte?

Tags: javascript, svelte

I'm working on a simple Todo App in Svelte. I recently added some edit functionality, which is a little buggy. Initially there is only an input with a submit button. Under the hood, todo is bound using `bind:value` between the input value and the variable, todo.

Until I added the edit functionality, I didn't notice the bug. However, the binding between todo and the input field does not cease to exist when the submit button is clicked. I'm curious if there is a way to remove a binding as a side effect to an event?

App

```js
<script>
  import AddTodo from "./AddTodo.svelte";
  import DisplayTodoItem from "./DisplayTodoItem.svelte";
  let todoItems = [];

  const handleTodoButtonClick = event => {
    todoItems = [...todoItems, event.detail.value];
  };

  const handleDeleteButtonClick = event => {
    todoItems = todoItems.filter(value => value != event.detail.value);
  };
</script>

<style>
  main {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
  }
</style>

<main>
  <AddTodo on:addTodoMessage={handleTodoButtonClick}/>
  {#each todoItems as item}
    <DisplayTodoItem item={item} on:deleteItemMessage={handleDeleteButtonClick}/>
  {/each}
</main>
```

AddTodo

```
<script>
  import { createEventDispatcher } from "svelte";
  const dispatch = createEventDispatcher();
  let todo;
</script>

<input bind:value={todo}>
<button on:click={ ()=>{dispatch('addTodoMessage', {value:todo})} }> submit  </button>
```

DisplayTodoItem

```js
<script>
 import { createEventDispatcher } from "svelte";
 const dispatch = createEventDispatcher();
 export let item;
 let notEdit = true;
</script>

{#if notEdit}
<div style="display: inline;">
  <h1> {item} </h1>
  <button on:click={ () => dispatch('deleteItemMessage', {value:item} )}>
    delete 
  </button>

  <button on:click={()=> notEdit=false}> edit</button>
</div>

{:else}
<input bind:value={item}/>
<button on:click={()=> notEdit=true}> Done editing </button>

{/if}
```

Ideally, after clicking submit and adding a todo to the array todoItems, the binding would be removed, such that buggy behavior did not occur later when edits to todoItems occur.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

The item is not bound, so the changes are not saved in the list, you need:

```html
<DisplayTodoItem bind:item .../>
```

Otherwise, any update will load the original value from when the item was added. It has nothing to do with the add input, that is entirely separate.

(Also, when removing items not just from the end, one should use a [keyed `{#each}`](https://svelte.dev/docs#template-syntax-each) and the delete will remove *all items* with the same value. Maybe switch that to index-based if the items are primitive values.)

Comment: Like so ` <DisplayTodoItem bind:item={item} on:deleteItemMessage={handleDeleteButtonClick}/>` ? Not sure if the `={item}` is still necessary.

Comment: Also, now if I click edit and make a change to the input, the change is automatically saved after the first keystroke. Do I need to modify the event with preventDefault?

Comment: `={item}` is not required if the name is the same. If you don't want changes to be saved immediately then don't use `bind:value` in `DisplayTodoItem` or bind to a temporary variable instead.

Comment: Alternatively, don't use any bindings and use events instead...

Comment: I’m using events in several places, but yes, as you noted, not in the edit functionality. That’s probably the right design decision.